# "His affection for the melting pot expressed, too, the personal delight he took in crossing social boundaries and meeting diverse groups of people”

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> *"His affection for the melting pot expressed, too, the personal delight he took in crossing social boundaries and meeting diverse groups of people”*

This is a quote from "Duties Of American Citizenship" by Theodore Roosevelt.

I kind of don't get it. I have tried searching it up but it still makes no sense at all. Can Someone explain it to me please...

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting_pot) explains a melting pot, your quote looks context-free.

Comment: What don't you understand about the sentence? There's a lot here. Can you focus your question a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

The melting pot is a metaphor for a society of initially diverse people becoming more homogeneous from cultural standpoint. The first thing to come to my head is the US cities that often were called so because a lot of very different people from all around the globe arrived there and finally formed a new distinctive culture which took traits and features of many nations.

Thus the phrase should mean that someone's positive view on and attitude to that characteristic feature of the society which united very different people to create a new culture expressed their delight to cross boundaries and embrace diversity of many nations and cultures.

Refer to the respective [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting_pot) article for more information as JonMark Perry has already suggested in a comment to your question.